# Docker RUN command works in container but not when building an image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, x86-64

I am trying to add another layer to a Docker Image that I built, this way updating openssl to v1.1.1. If I run the following commands in my container, everything works perfectly:

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1n.tar.gz
tar -xzf openssl-1.1.1n.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1n
./config --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl shared
make
make INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/root/openssl install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64
ldconfig
```

However, when I add these commands in my Dockerfile and build the image (*docker build .*) I get the following error:

```
Step 40/51 : RUN ./config --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl shared
 ---> Running in 3c2ffa572bf1
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2
Can't locate FindBin.pm in @INC (you may need to install the FindBin module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/lib/perl/site_perl/5.22.1/ /usr/lib/perl/site_perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/perl/vendor_perl/5.22.1/ /usr/lib/perl/vendor_perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/perl/5.22.1/ /usr/lib/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/perl/5.22.1 .) at ./Configure line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./Configure line 15.
Can't locate FindBin.pm in @INC (you may need to install the FindBin module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/lib/perl/site_perl/5.22.1/ /usr/lib/perl/site_perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/perl/vendor_perl/5.22.1/ /usr/lib/perl/vendor_perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/perl/5.22.1/ /usr/lib/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/perl/5.22.1 .) at ./Configure line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./Configure line 15.
This system (linux-x86_64) is not supported. See file INSTALL for details.
The command '/bin/sh -c ./config --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl shared' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Does anyone know why is this happening? Thank you!

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What's gone into the previous 40 steps of the Dockerfile; what's the fewest of these that you need to demonstrate the problem?  Can you use a prebuilt OpenSSL package from the base Linux distribution instead of building it from source?

Comment: If you just add RUN in front of each command, then there are some commands that don't work due to the way Docker build works. For instance, the `cd` and the `export` commands don't do anything.